# Calling <div>s in :hover selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to affect multiple divs on a single `:hover`.  For instance, two divs floated left and right of each other.  When a `:hover` statement over one of them is activated (or, probably over a parent `div`) I would like for both of them to change width, color, opacity, etc.

```
<div id='maincontainer'>
    <div id='mainleft'>
     Left div that shrinks on maincontainer:hover
    </div>
    <div id='mainright'>
    Right div that grows on maincontainer:hover
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need a container div for this?  Is this even possible in CSS alone?

Comment: With the JavaScript plugin of course @prabhavith ;)

Comment: I knew I could do some really cool stuff with JavaScript, but I know absolutely nothing about it fundamentally and I wanted to flex my CSS muscles at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use

```
#maincontainer:hover #mainleft { ... }
#maincontainer:hover #mainright { ... }
```

and change your css properly. This will work everywhere except IE<7 which allows `hover` only for `<a>` elements

You could also think to trigger a CSS transition on newer browser so the size of inner divs change gradually.

Answer (score 1):

By using this css it would be possible

```
​#maincontainer:hover #mainleft{
 width: 100px;   
}

#maincontainer:hover #mainright{
 width: 200px;   
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how u can do it with javascript
i prefer javascript because older browser restrict hover only to anchor tags

```
document.getElementById("maincontainer").onmouseover = func;

function func(event){
     document.getElementById("mainleft").style.width = newwidth + px;
     document.getElementById("mainright").style.width = newwidth + px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to apply css for both:

```
#maincontainer > div:hover { *your css* }
```

Answer (score 0):

`#maincontainer:hover #mainleft` css selector will match `mainleft` div when the `maincontainer` is hovered.